# friend function of a template class that has different template parameters as input

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have class for floating point format where the size of the mantissa and the exponent can be specified as a template parameter:

```
template <int _m_size, int _exp_size>
class fpxx {

public:
    const int exp_size      = _exp_size;
    const int m_size        = _m_size;

    bool        sign;
    unsigned    exp;
    unsigned    m;
    ...
}
```

I also have a friend operator+ to add 2 such numbers:

```
friend fpxx<_m_size, _exp_size>  operator+(const fpxx<_m_size, _exp_size> left, const fpxx<_m_size, _exp_size> right) 
{
    ...
}
```

This works fine.

It allows me to do things like this:

```
fpxx<18,5> a, b, r;
r = a + b;
```

However, I would also be able create an operator+ friend that makes it possible to add numbers with different mantissa and exponent sizes. 
Like this:

```
fpxx<10,4> a;
fpxx<12,4> a;
fpxx<18,5> r;
r = a + b;
```

But I have no idea how to do declare the function for that.

Is this possible?

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: Make it its own template.  Also, something isn't matching here.  `fpxx` takes 2 non type parameters but you define your friend function using 3.

Comment: I've edited my example. I had simplified it before submitting, but I hadn't simplified it everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your operator template and make it `friend`, something like:

```
template <int _m_size, int _exp_size>
class fpxx {

public:
    const int exp_size      = _exp_size;
    const int m_size        = _m_size;

    bool        sign;
    unsigned    exp;
    unsigned    m;

template <int s1, int e1, int s2, int e2>
friend fpxx</*..*/> operator+(const fpxx<s1, e1>& left, const fpxx<s2, e2>& right);

};

template <int s1, int e1, int s2, int e2>
fpxx</*..*/> operator+(const fpxx<s1, e1>& left, const fpxx<s2, e2>& right)
{
    //...
}
```

Notice that return type should be fixed at compile time.

Comment: Thanks! That's getting me a whole lot further. However, after adding this, I now get  an "ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’" error and "note: candidate: operator+(float, float) <built-in>". I think this is because I also a " operator float () const " operator. How do I make it know that it should use the + operator instead of the type conversion operator?

Comment: Create a new Question.